# Esconder botão caso valor da label for X

Tags: php, html, button

Criei uma página que gera um código de verificação pra pessoa quando ela clicka no botão "Gerar", assim, a página atualiza e o código é mostrado, como faço para o botão dessa página só aparecer quando ela não tiver gerado o código? (Quando ela não tem nada da database aparece "Click no Botão Gerar", e quando ela já esta verificada na linha aparece VERIFICADO) Segue abaixo o código da página

````
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <?php
    $pagina_name = User::userData('username'); ?>
    <body>

        <?php include 'templates/GalaxyServers/includes/header.php' ?>
        <?php include 'templates/GalaxyServers/includes/head-config.php' ?>
                       <?php
                        if (isset($_POST['salvarusuario']))
                        {
                            $usernamevariable =User::userData('username');

                            $upateUser = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `verifica_discord`= :discord WHERE `username`= :id");
                            $upateUser->bindParam(':discord', $_POST['discord']); 
                            $upateUser->bindParam(':id', $usernamevariable); 
                            $upateUser->execute(); 
                            echo'<div class="alert alert-info">Código Gerado!</div>';

                        }
                        ?>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

 </div>

                <div class="col-lg-11">
                    <div class="panel panel-default" id="box-content">
                        <div class="panel-heading" id="box-title"><strong>Acesso Ao Discord Do Hotel </strong>
                        </i></small></div>
                        <p><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;Click no botão abaixo para gerar um código para o discord! Depois de gerado, basta enviar no canal de verificações em nosso servidor!</strong></p>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                          <div class="form-group">
                                         <?php 
               if(User::userData('verifica_discord') != null) { $verifica_discord = User::userData('verifica_discord'); } else { $verifica_discord = 'Click No Botão Gerar';} ?>
                                        <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Código Discord</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text"  value="<?= $verifica_discord ?>" name="verifica_discord" class="form-control" readonly>
             <br>
             <form class="form-horizontal form-element col-12" action="" name = "salvarusuario" method="POST">
                          <button style="width: 140px;
                                        float: right;
                                        margin-bottom: 14px;" type="submit" name="salvarusuario" class="btn btn-success">Gerar</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><Br><br>
                                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="hidden"  value="<?php echo rand(1, 99999999999); ?>" name="discord" class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                    </div><Br><br>
                                                <?php
                                                include_once 'includes/footer.php';
                                                ?>```
````

Answer (score -2):

Primeiro você teria que buscar uma forma de vincular a pessoa ao código gerado. Provavelmente um usuário. Eu recomendo fazer um select e vincular a sessão vigente (pode ser no seu objeto User). Poderia criar um método `User::getCode()`. Ai para esconder o botão, você usaria a mesma verificação que fez para exibir a mensagem "clique no botão gerar", basta colocar um if  entre o elemento html :)

Comment: Não tem como por ex: se na <input> tiver o valor VERIFICADO ou algum número o botão não aparecer? Ou só o botão aparecer quando não tiver nada (Click Aqui Para Gerar)?

Comment: Porque as pessoas já estão vinculadas ao código (O Site possui login e etc), logo quando ela se verifica no discord, o bot troca o código dela na database pelo "VERIFICADO", ou assim que ela gera, já é inserido no usuário dela o código numa coluna